# SASS variables into :root are not interpolated

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, scss-mixins

I want to override base-font-size by calling a function, its definition is given below

[base-font-size variable is defined in the root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KygBx.png)

```
export const changeBaseFontSize = (newSize: string) => {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--base-font-size", newSize);
};
```

Calling this function as given below

```
changeBaseFontSize("16");
```

Now, I have a function which will convert the provided pixel value into rem depending upon the base-font-size value

```
@function pxToRem($pxValue) {
  $baseFont: var(--base-font-size);
  $remValue: #{$pxValue / $baseFont};
  @return $remValue + rem;
}
```

Now when I am calling this function from scss file as given below

```
.n-code-input-field {
  border-radius: pxToRem(16);
}
```

When I am running this code it is applying the styles as given below

```
.n-code-input-field {
    border-radius: 16/var(--base-font-size)rem;
}
```

These border styles are not working

but If I directly add the base-font-size as 16 it is working fine

```
@function pxToRem($pxValue) {
  $baseFont: 16;
  $remValue: #{$pxValue / $baseFont};
  @return $remValue + rem;
}
```

This is working fine as it is returning 1rem

```
@function pxToRem($pxValue) {
  $baseFont: 16;
  $remValue: #{$pxValue / $baseFont};
  @return $remValue + rem;
}
```

`border-radius: 1rem;`

How Can I fix it?

Ideally It should return the calculated rem value

Comment: SASS variables are calculated at compile time, you can't change them at runtime

Comment: You could try to tweak your function: `@function pxToRem($pxValue) {
  $baseFont: var(--base-font-size);
  $remValue: calc(#{$pxValue / $baseFont} * 1rem);
  @return $remValue;
}`

Comment: @AmauryHanser this thing is giving errors at compile time, 
```
Undefined operation "16px/var(--base-font-size) * 1rem".
  ╷
3 │   $remValue: $pxValue / $baseFontSize * 1rem;
  │              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/base/functions.scss 3:14         pxToRem()
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible as it would require time travel. Literally.

You are trying to read a CSS variable's value (only available at ***run-time***) inside SCSS functions (which run at ***build-time***).

By the time the CSS value has been populated (by DOM inheritance), the SCSS has already been compiled into CSS. Which means the functions you're writing would have already been run.

---

Another way to put it: SCSS gets compiled into CSS on the server. CSS variables are populated in the browser. You're trying to read on the server values which will be populated when the CSS is run by the browser.

Comment: Is there any approach which can be followed to achieve this?

Comment: @Anil, there's always a way. Can you explain the problem you're trying to solve? Last time I needed something like this was when I had to use two different Bootstrap versions on the same page (3 and 4). I had to replace all `rem`-based values in one of them with `calc()` functions. And it worked. So, give me an example of what you're trying to achieve and I'll tell you how it can be achieved. So far you've presented an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I'd like to remind you there's already a native mechanism for this conversion in place. All you need to do is change the `font-size` on the `<body>` element to a different pixels value. However, the crux of the problem is that you are limited to CSS functions (e.g. `calc()`). You can't use SASS functions.

Comment: I have a library which is using 10px as base font, because of this If I use this library in any project I won't be able to use third-party libraries as most of the libraries are using 16px as base font. Now I want to make my library customizable so that the whole scss will be replaced by new styles based on the base-font-size provided by the user. I was trying to use a variable that can be provided  by the env variable or by using some other way. and based on that variable I will provide the new components which will be using the provided base-font-size.

Comment: CSS variables are only available at runtime. The only option is to return a `calc()` from the sass function, which will be calculated at runtime. The cleaner approach would be to modify your lib to use the default `16px` value for `1rem`. So when the end user changes font-size, your components change accordingly.

Comment: Another note: **not all** properties should be given in `rem`. Only those related to text rendering and readability. (e.g: margins, paddings, widths, heights, gaps, etc...). Do not use rem values for borders, shadows, outlines, dropdown positioning, or anything that doesn't touch on text rendering. The logic is: do I want this to change when the font-size changes? If yes, use `rem` values. If not, use `px`.

Comment: Relative lengths are still preferable to absolute in most cases. Media queries should use rem to reflect the accessibility settings (browser font size - not zoom) to avoid layout collapse. Yes, a 1px border is probably OK, but in general use rem (or em at component level for dynamic sizing).

Comment: @Jakob, changing font size should not act as a scale factor for anything other than text. The `rem` value can be overwritten by browser accessibility plugins for visually impaired users. And what happens is that borders will appear as if they have variable width, depending on whether they are vertical or horizontal and where they land on the pixel, creating visual artefacts. This also happens for shadows. Rarely, but it happens. Linking elements which have nothing to do with text legibility to font-size opens the door for a host of problems which could be avoided. It's simply low quality UI.

Comment: Why do you think Bootstrap uses `px` for `border` and `box-shadow`? Because they don't care about accessibility? Or could it be because their lib is battle tested in all possible browsers with all possible rendering engines, on all possible devices?

Comment: Using relative units will make your layout follow your content size. If you like it to break in case of user preferences - then go ahead... Also I did mention border as a non-crucial element ;-). I've been doing CSS for 20+ years - I'm not a newbie

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Amaury Hanser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7100628/amaury-hanser) you can return a calc value. Note the fallback value in var(--base-font-size, 16) in case --base-font-size is not defined

```
:root {
    --base-font-size: 16;
}

@function pxToRem($pxValue) {
    // Use either 1 or 2
    // 1. Decrease font size at higher base-font-size
    @return calc(#{$pxValue} / var(--base-font-size, 16) * 1rem);

    // 2. Increase font size at higher base-font-size
    @return calc(#{$pxValue / 16} * var(--base-font-size, 16) / 16  * 1rem);

}


h1 {
    // Will render 
    // 1.  font-size: calc(64 / var(--base-font-size, 16) * 1rem)
    // 2.  font-size: calc(4 * var(--base-font-size, 16)/ 16 * 1rem)
    font-size: pxToRem(64);
}
```

---

**Demo of output*** (to show downvoters it works ;-)

*stack overflow does not support Sass

```js
addEventListener('input',({target: { value }})=>{
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--base-font-size',value);
  val.innerText = value
})
```

```css
/* This is the CSS output from the Sass code above */
:root {
  --base-font-size: 16;
}

/* version 1 */
.v1 {
  font-size: calc(64 / var(--base-font-size, 16) * 1rem);
}

/* version 2 */
.v2 {
  font-size: calc(4 * var(--base-font-size, 16)/ 16 * 1rem);
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
   <legend>Base font size</legend>
   <input type="range" min="1" max="32" value="16" /><output id="val">16</output>
</fieldset>
<h1>
  <span class="v1">Version 1</span> <span class="v2">Version 2</span>  
</h1>
```

**Update 1**

The original example was based on the provided math that will increase font size if lowered. If you want the opposite to be true use version 2 (based on a 16px rem value)

**Update 2**

If you want ***all*** rem values to scale you could set the base font size (scale) as a percentage on the root element - this will work like the often seen 62.5% document font size

```
:root {
  // If base font size is provided as integer 
  --base-font-scale: 100;
  font-size: calc(var(--base-font-scale) * 1%);

  // If base font size is provided as percentage
  font-size: var(--base-font-scale, 100%); 
}

@function pxToRem($pxValue) {
    @return $pxValue / 16 * 1rem; 
}

h1 {
   // Will render font-size: 4rem
   font-size: pxToRem(64);
}

h2 {
   // Unlike version 1+2 this will also scale 
   font-size: 2rem;
}
```

**Note!**

A small side note on Sass units. Wen using calculations use multiply rather than adding 'rem' unit as a string

```
$font-size: 10 + rem;        // this becomes a string value ("rem")
$font-size: $font-size * 2;  // this won't work :-(   

$font-size: 10 * 1rem;       // this is a valid 10rem unit
$font-size: $font-size * 2;  // this will work :-)
```

Comment: If you return a `calc()` then it's a CSS function, not an SCSS one. It runs at runtime. The question was how to use a runtime value into an SCSS function. I never said this computation cannot be performed at runtime, using CSS functions (`calc`, `min`, `max`, etc...). But you can't use runtime values in SCSS functions. Your answer is misleading and, IMHO,  detrimental, especially to less than seasoned developers.

Comment: To understand the difference, try using your technique with core SCSS functions, such as color parsers (`hue`, `mix`, etc...).

Comment: Providing a working solution is not misleading when the question is "how to fix". I'm fully aware of the difference between compile and runtime variables (I've posted about this back in 2017).

Comment: Indeed, the *"fix"* is any solution that *does not use runtime values in SCSS functions*, CSS functions and JavaScript based solutions included. I think it is important for future readers, as well as for OP, to understand the nature of the problem before deciding on a working solution, catered to their requirements.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with mixing both. The Sass function helps ease implementation and the runtime ensures the bridge to the JS interface shown first in the question. It is not about one or the other but about making it work... and this brings the best of both worlds